# Custom reports not showing any Data

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, analytics

I have setup Google Analytics script in my web site, I am using [Analytics.js](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/)

```
<script type='text/javascript'>

  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');



  ga('create', 'UA-xxxxxxxx-1', 'wfihotspotnet.in');
  ga('send', 'pageview');


  var dimensionValue1="21";
  ga('set', 'dimension1', dimensionValue1);
  var dimensionValue2="male";
  ga('set', 'dimension2', dimensionValue2);
  var dimensionValue3="India";
ga('set', 'dimension3', dimensionValue3);


</script>
```

In My Custom Reports Dashboard I have created Three reports with,

Custom Dimension `Age` and Metrics `Pageview`

Similarly for `Gender` vs `PageView` and Location vs Pageview

I have more than 400 Pageviews but In custom Dimension No data is displayed

I used Chrome GA.debug Extension and it is displaying that data is processed

***what silly Mistake I have done ?***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have sent your pageview before you've set the dimensions. Custom dimensions need an interaction call to be sent to the server so in your example they are not event sent. Move the "set" calls between the lines that create the tracker and the pageview call and you should be fine.

Comment: `ga('send', 'pageview');` so moving this to end of the script will work fine

Comment: how much time I have to wait, I have corrected as you have said. can I check dimensions in real time tab in dashboard

Comment: Depends on the traffic volume for your site. Google says data processing take from at least 4 to max. 48 hours (however on a medium traffic site I would expect data to turn up afer a few hours).